# Matlab ObjectOrientated Programming Vectorize

Tags: matlab, oop, vectorization

I want to create a simulation for a real-world problem and use object orientated programming.

For example I have a class like this:

```
classdef person
  properties
    name     % string
    age      % integer
    height   % double (was called 'size' before - which might be a bad idea, see post below)
  end
end
```

now a single person I can create by

```
p1 = person;
```

and give it properties by

```
p1.name = 'Karl';
p1.age = 35;
p1.size = 1.80;
```

so we have an individual person named Karl, that is 35 years old and 1.80m tall.

What I now want is a matrix, say I have a `matrix1` of an island, where all entries with `0` are water and all entries with `1` represent land. Now I want to populate the land randomly with people, such that everywhere, where is "land" on `matrix1` there can be placed a `person` in `matrix2`, everything else is 0 again.

**First:** Is there a way to vectorize this? How do I create such a Matrix very fast, instead of initializing this element by element with two for-loops?

**Second:** And then, how can I have vecorized access to the data? (like `old_ppl = matrix2(person.age >= 50)`)

Comment: first intuition if you want to be able to vectorise operations on series of objects, you will have to create a `personCollection` object which can gather all these persons and in this collection class implement a method which can take/handle vectorised input/output.

Comment: **first** Do you want a randomly sorted matrix of 0,1? If so just generate a random matrix e.g. `A=rand(1000)` returns a 1000x1000 matrix with values going from 0 to 1. Now you do `A(A<0.5)=0;A(A>=0.5)=1;` and you get a random matrix with 0,1. Now with your second matrix... Do you want those people randomly placed on your "land"? And do you have enough people to fill a matrix which would be completely ones? Unlikely but possible after all.

Comment: yes, they should be placed randomly on the land

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, recognize that you can't have an array where some of the elements are of class `person` and some of the elements are `0` - if it's an array, then all the elements have to be of the same class.

You can use a cell array (rather than an array) to do this, and that would be one solution for you.

Another way would be to create an abstract class `AbstractPerson`, inheriting from `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous`, and then have two subclasses `RealPerson` and `NullPerson` that inherit from `AbstractPerson`. In this way you would be able to construct an array of class `AbstractPerson` that contained elements of class `RealPerson` and `NullPerson` in the right places. That would be another solution for you. I'm not sure whether your example is a toy problem or a real-world problem; for toy problems this method is almost certainly a huge overkill, but for real-world problems it might well not be.

You could vectorize the construction of either of the above solutions fairly straightforwardly.

However, neither of these solutions are really very efficient, as they're not really taking advantage of MATLAB's strengths. Instead of trying to construct an array containing `Person` objects, why not instead do it the other way around and construct a single `People` object that contains arrays?

For example:

```
classdef People
    properties
        names   % nxm cell array of strings
        ages    % nxm array of integers
        heights % nxm array of heights
    end
end
```

(NB note that I've called the property `height` rather than `size` - it's a very bad idea in MATLAB to name anything `size`, as that's a really basic built-in function).

`names`, `ages` and `heights` would simply be empty strings or NaN where there was no person present. If you wanted, you could have an extra property `isPresent` that was an nxm logical array, that you could use to conveniently manage positions where there were people or not. To ensure consistency between the arrays, make them `SetAccess = private`, and give it a method `addPerson(name, age, height, position)` that will add a person in the correct position while ensuring that the arrays remain consistent in size and class etc.

That would be much more efficient and take advantage of MATLAB's strengths.

Comment: I edited my post, yes it is a real-world-problem and the `isPresent` Property is a good idea. I will try some things this weekend and look, what will suit best. Thank you, you actually could help me a bit :)